# Using JavaScript function from HTML Button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with XDK and want to add an html button which should call a JS function. The JS file was created in the project and is included with `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>`

My button code is:

```
<form>
    <input id="change_button" type="button" value="Change" onClick="change();"/>
</form>
```

And my JS function:

```
function change() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

For some reason nothing happens when I press the button. Maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for any hints how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

First, you may check if your button is working at all:

```
<form>
    <input id="change_button" type="button" value="Change" onClick="alert('smth');"/>
</form>
```

Then you can check if the function is visible globally: open browser console and try `change();`. Also, as Nghi Nguyen have suggested, you may see some errors there.

One of the two should fail since the button fails.

Answer (score 3):

the function should work, however check the path of your app.js file

Comment: Thanks! I just used the whole path to the folder where the app.js is located. Sometimes it's to easy to see. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems very simple.  You can actually execute javascript directly from an `onclick` attribute. Maybe just try `input id="change_button" type="button" value="Change" onClick="alert('Hello, I am an alert box!!');"`